# Excel Graph numbers column with text column that is duplicated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in excel I need to graph. One is number type and one is text.
The problem is that the text is full of duplicated values as shown below.

We only need to use 1 single value of each string.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1.25 | textA |
| 1.25 | textA |
| 1.54 | textA |
| 13.5 | textB |
| 158.5 | textA |
| 13.36 | textB |
| 3.3 | textA |
| 0.25 | textA |

Any idea what is the formula to be used?

Comment: what is the expected result? what kind of chart? and how should it look like?

Comment: bar chart @YairMaron

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pivot Chart, like this:

- Axis: `Column B`
- Values: `Column A` --> change settings to use Min function:

[image: PivotChart fields pane]

Then your chart would look like this:

[image: Chart preview]